# object not serializable kmeans model spark mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running the code below:

```
def calcClusteringScores(data: RDD[Vector], k: Int) : Double = {
  val model = KMeans.train(data=data, k, maxIterations = 1)
  data.map(datum => distanceToCentroid(datum, model)).mean()
}
```

`KMeans.train` returns a `KMeansModel` (see: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/KMeansModel.html)) which implements serializable and should be serializable.

However when I run the `data.map` function, I get an `object not serializable` exception complaining about the model. Is there a way to resolve this, that I am missing?

#### Update 1

Below is the distanceToCentroid method, which calls the distance. Which calculates euclidean distance between 2 vectors

```
def distanceToCentroid(datum: Vector, model: KMeansModel) : Double ={
    val cluster = model.predict(datum)
    val clusterCenter = model.clusterCenters(cluster)
    distance(datum, clusterCenter)                     
  }

def distance(a: Vector, b: Vector) : Double ={
  val a_arr = a.toArray
  val b_arr = b.toArray
  val pairs = a_arr.zip(b_arr)
  val sumOfSquares = pairs.map(pair => pair._1 - pair._2)
                          .map(diff => diff * diff)
                          .sum
  sqrt(sumOfSquares)
}
```

#### Update 2

I fixed the serialisation issue by moving the method bodies from the functions into the main method. I no longer get the serialisation error, but I dont know why. Anyone have any ideas?

```
def testSerialiseModel() ={
    val sparkConf     = new SparkConf().setAppName("ModelTest").setMaster("local")
    val sc            = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sparkSession  = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

    val data = sc.parallelize(Array(
      Vectors.dense(Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)),
      Vectors.dense(Array(1.0, 1.8, 2.3)),
      Vectors.dense(Array(2.0, 1.5, 3.0))
   ))

    val model = KMeans.train(data=data, 2, maxIterations = 1)

    val score = data.map{datum =>
      val cluster = model.predict(datum)
      val clusterCenter = model.clusterCenters(cluster)

      val pairs = datum.toArray.zip(clusterCenter.toArray)
      val sumOfSquares = pairs.map(pair => pair._1 - pair._2)
                        .map(diff => diff * diff)
                        .sum
      sqrt(sumOfSquares)

    }.mean()

    println(s"clustering score: ${score}")
}
```

Comment: What is `distanceToCentroid`? I can't reproduce your error because of it and I can't find it on the documentation of `KMeans`. Just fyi, I don't get any errors when I run your code without the `data.map` part inside your definition, so it can't be a problem related to `KMeans` model. Perhaps you defined the method `distanceToCentroid` using RDD's and this method is not serialized. Pobably that's why your getting the error

Comment: What about getting the centroids as a vector before calling `distanceToCentroid` using `clusterCenters()`? Or if you want the cost of the whole dataset you could use the `computeCost` method.

Comment: @user322778 thanks. I have updated the question to show the distanceToCentroid method.

Comment: @Shaido thanks, model.clusterCenters(cluster) already returns a vector

Comment: Where are you running your code? I ran your code including the `distanceToCentroid`part without any error (I'm using Cloudera virtual machine 5.8.0)

Comment: Maybe this helps to answer your question https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/22/using-non-serializable-objects-in-apache-spark/

Comment: @user322778 I'm running it as a unit test locally, but the blog link did help thanks. If I turn my class into an object there are no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The functions were within a scala `class` changing the class to object as recommended by post linked by @user322778 solved the issue. The class didnt have any instance variables so it was trivial to change to an object.